# How to keep a flow alive on errors / restart it?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow, android-architecture

In my Android ViewModel I have code like this:

```
try {
    myRepository
        .getAllData()
        .catch {
            Timber.e("catch exception case 1")
            Timber.e(it)
        }
        .collect { data ->
            // use data to set UI state
            uiState = uiState.copy(data = data)
        }
} catch(e: Exception) {
    Timber.e("catch exception case 2")
    Timber.e(e)
    // how to keep the flow alive or restart it?
}
```

1. During testing I reached `catch exception case 2`. In this case I want to display an error to the user, but keep the `Flow` alive (e.g. if users presses a retry button which could then send successful data over the `Flow`). However in my understanding the `Flow` is automatically cancelled due to the exception? How to restart the `Flow` or prevent it from being cancelled at all?
2. In which case would one reach `catch exception case 1`?

Comment: have you perhaps caught a `CancellationException`?

Comment: no, I don't catch any exceptions before that / in the underlying layers. It's actually an Apolloexception that comes from the deepest layer at all. Just want to keep the flow alive so it gets the data on the next attempt (e.g. user clicks refresh button)

Comment: Exception case 1 should happen if `getAllData` flow fails. Exception case 2 would happen if `getAllData` itself throws (before it returns a flow), flow is cancelled (`CancellationException` I mentioned above) or your `uiState.copy` throws but I don't think that's the case right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`retryWhen`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/retry-when.html) instead of `catch`, it's the most powerful operator for working with exceptions in `Flow`.

It allows you to:

- Inspect `Throwable`
- Emit new values
- Restart the original `Flow`.

Conceptually you could do something like this:

```kotlin
    myRepository
        .getAllData()
        .retryWhen { cause, attempt ->
            Timber.e("catch exception case 1")
            Timber.e(it)

            // Emit UiState downstream to show error
            emit(UiState.Error(cause))

            // Or predicate based on cause
            true
        }
        .collect { data ->
            // use data to set UI state
            uiState = uiState.copy(data = data)
        }
```

Unless `uiState = uiState.copy(data = data)` can throw an exception, which I assume it won't. This code will never fail.

To make it fail, you should either return `false` to `retryWhen` or re throw a different exception from within `retryWhen`.